# Riemann Integrability over [1,5]

Tags: real-analysis, permutations, riemann-sum

I am trying to design a question that makes sense.

First, I consider the greatest integer function on an interval$ [1,5]$. This throws up $1,2,3,4$ and $5$. Then I wish to permute these numbers by $(1 3 2)(4 5)$. This means all the $x$ which lies on $[1,2)$ gets mapped to $3$, all the $x$ which lies on $[2,3)$ gets mapped to $1$ and so forth.

Next, I want to ask people to test its Riemann Integrability over $[1,5]$. Of course, it is not!

Well, would it make sense if I ask-

---

Let $f:[1,5] \to R , h:[1,5] \to R$ and $ g=(1 3 2)(4 5)$  where

$f$ is the function composition given by $f= goh$,
$h(x) = [x]$ is the greatest integer function of $x \in [1,5]$ and
$g = (1 3 2)(4 5)$.

If $f$ a Riemann Integrable function on $[1,5]$?

Comment: Is the range of $f$, subset of $\mathbb Z$ and  it is finite set ? (If yes, then it seems answer is yes!)

Comment: @Inquisitive : Yes, the range of $f$ is just ${1,2,3,4,5}$.

Comment: @Inquisitive : No, $f$ is not Riemann Integrable. Look at the upper sums and lower sums. Consider the partition as {1,2,3,4,5}

Comment: Your function is continuous except in a set of measure zero, hence *it is* Riemann integrable. The value of the integral is just $1+2+3+4+5=15$ as expected, disregarding the manipulations on the domain.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio : Yeah, you are right in the fact that it is riemann integrable over [1,5]. Oops! But the Riemann sum would be 3+1+2+5 = 11. What I had done was that on [1,2], I had taken min = 1 and max=3... the same for other partitions!Hence, the error. Yeah, I needed to exclude the points 2,3 and 4 in a $\delta$ neighbourhood.

Comment: .....and 5 too!